# Receiving email on Meteor?

Tags: meteor, email

From the documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#email), it seems sending email is fairly straight forward with Meteor. Just need to add the package, then specify the credentials of your 3rd party email provider in MAIL_URL.

Currently, I'm trying to develop the ability to receive emails. We need this facility to say unsubscribe a user from our system or allow users to input data by just replying to their email.

I just want to know, what is the best way to do this? Is it possible to receive and parse the emails from within my Meteor solution or do I need to set up something seperate solution to do this?

If it helps, I'm running a meteor website off an azure VM (in ubuntu) and our 3rd party provider is SendGrid.

Comment: Do you have email receiving on the machine and the DNS MZ record and all that already set up? Or is that part of the question?

Comment: @ChristianF : No I don't sorry. I only have the ability to send emails from Meteor at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also an Evangelist at SendGrid. Here is the procedure for receiving inbound email with our parse webhook in Meteor:

1. Setup Meteorite a package manager for meteor. Installation procedure here: https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite
2. Run `mrt add router` in the command line.
3. Next modify your javascript to add a route:

> Meteor.Router.add({ '/inbound': function() {
>
> post = this.request.body;
>
> subject = post.subject;
>
> body = post.body;
>
> return [200, "Success"] } });

You can see a live example of receiving inbound email over here: http://hook.meteor.com and the source code for this is available here: https://github.com/kunal732/sgmeteor

Here is a blog post I wrote on the topic as well for more reference, http://sendgrid.com/blog/receive-inbound-email-meteorjs/

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to setup your machine (or another one) to actually be able to receive email. This in itself is a bit of a task and not super straightforward and will involve setting a MX record on your nameserver as well. It will require some reading. This might be a place to get started:
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/mail-setup.html

Once you have the ability to send email to the server you can use something like this to retrieve emails into node/meteor:
https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap
https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/meteor-node-imap

If you'd rather have node.js itself run a smtp server to receive mail, you would probably want to look at something like this:
https://npmjs.org/package/simplesmtp

Comment: Notice: simplesmtp is deprecated and the server is not working (for me) using node v0.10+  -- try [smtp-server](https://github.com/andris9/smtp-server) instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to receive email, you have 2 major options:

**First Option**

The first is to setup an email server to receive email, store that email, and access it. I'd recommend [Haraka](https://github.com/baudehlo/Haraka) to do this. You can install it on your server, run it, and then add a plugin like [haraka-couchdb](https://github.com/maxogden/haraka-couchdb) or [haraka-redis](http://github.com/scottmotte/haraka-redis) to store the emails into a database. Then you could simply query that database and pull the email content out. Then you just have to parse it. (I find this approach easier than setting up postfix with IMAP support and keep that running)

**Second Option**

The second option is to use SendGrid's Parse Webhook (since you're already a customer with us - disclaimer: I'm a developer evangelist with SendGrid). There's a beginners guide to do this here:

http://sendgrid.com/blog/parse-webhook-tutorial/

And an example application here:

https://github.com/scottmotte/sendgrid-parse-api-example